# How to get a reference to the PHAsset from an image URL in the iOS Extension?

Tags: ios, swift

I’m working on an Apple Photos Extension. I need to get the photos HDR and Depth Effect flags from the PHAsset. The Extension only seems to give me a URL to a temp image file and not a reference to the PHAsset. In other words, I need to get the object of PHAsset from the Extension image URL (or some other way) so I can get the HDR and Depth Effect attributes.

```
for item: Any in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
 let inputItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
 for provider: Any in inputItem.attachments! {
      let itemProvider = provider as! NSItemProvider
  if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) { ......
```

Thank you so much,

Piyush

Comment: file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0007.PNG Did you have URL like this ?

Comment: No, I have url with temp directory

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know depth (100%) and HDR (not sure :P) are in the Image Properties. So do this to get them:

```
let options = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
//for icloud or itunes
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

//self is the PHAsset Object here this snippet is from an extenstion I made.            
self.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: {
                (contentEditingInput, _) -> Void in
     if contentEditingInput != nil {
         if let url = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL {
         //URL is the path of the File in the 
             if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil) {
                 if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
                     //Now you can access the metadata here depth should be in exif afaik
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the different Metadatas can be accessed through specific constants of [Image I/O](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimageproperties#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Canon_Camera_Dictionary_Keys)

Comment: Hi, I want to get PHAssest object from "contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL".

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand you right. Do you just want to access the data? Then the `imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil)` where url is `contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageUrl` would be the best way.

Comment: @PiyushParsaniya are you still struggling with the metadata? Do you need additional help?

Comment: Yes, I can not get PHAssest from selected image in Action Extension.